# Joomla!2.5 won't execute back end functions

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm such an amateur at Joomla, sometimes I think I don't even know what I'm doing.

I'm designing a quiz-like component, and set up a basic backend page, which displays questions and answers properly.

[image: Back End]

Upon clicking either of the toolbar options, though, they don't work. `Edit` and `New` lead me to a blank page, whereas `Delete` gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: 
Call to a member function load() on a non-object 
in D:\www\joomla17\libraries\joomla\application\component\modeladmin.php 
on line 652
```

I have absolutely no idea what could be wrong in here, since I've been introduced to Joomla for no longer than a month, and wasted the best part of this month tweaking frontend CSS (as I'm a designer).

Folder and file structure as far as the model folder goes is like this:

- folder: forms

  - reforcodigital.xml
- reforcodigital.php
- reforcodigitals.php

---

**Update:** My workmate pointed out that the buttons are pointing to a blank page, failing to give the server the proper request tags. Where in my system (models/controllers/helpers) should I check this error?

Comment: do you have a reforcodigital.php file in a tables folder in your component? The model will expect a class that extends JTable to exist. Typically that would be what the model is trying to use the `load` function on. Look at the bottom of this for an example of that file: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Using_the_database

Comment: Yes, I have this file, and the page doesn't load.